# MuseScore doesn't play sound

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I installed `mscore` on Ubuntu 14.04 as well as `fluidsynth`. I have not had Ubuntu sound problems to this day.

When I press the Play button, I get this:
[image: -]

There is no sound, and apparently the synthesizer (if there is one) is stuck at the first note. If it helps, some additional information would be that MuseScore temporarily mutes my system's other sounds.

Here are my synth settings:
[image]

**How can I make sound play in MuseScore?** I am reluctant simply to call it a bug.

---

EDIT: "What have you tried?"

I've tried [messing with sound I/O.](http://musescore.org/en/node/14651) I'm a member of the group `audio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to I/O and use Portaudio/ALSA for audio output.

[image: settings]

Presumably having added yourself to the group `audio`, change the "Device" to what looks most like the audio driver, for me, Intel (headphones) instead of default --- if you're not sure, try all of them.

Finally check that synth, play panel, mixer, and system volume levels are up.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. It helped to choose the right device under the "Portaudio" option.